# Show that $\int_{\mathbb \Gamma}\lambda^kd\lambda = 0 , \forall k \ge 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, contour-integration

Let $\mathbb \Gamma$ denote the boundary of a convex polygon with vertices $w_1, ..., w_n$ in $\mathbb C$.

**Show that**

$$\int_{\mathbb \Gamma}\lambda^kd\lambda = 0 , \forall k \ge 0$$

I've found some information regarding the question which could help me approach this (in the picture below). But I'm still struggling how to use contour integration in order to calculate the integral (show that it's equal to zero), when $f(\lambda) = \lambda^k$ for $k \ge 0$.

And also, another approach I was thinking of, using the following **Theorem** in order to solve the question:

[image]

**Some helpful background:**

[image]

Comment: Hint: start with a simple triangle, parametrize the triangle and show that the integral have value zero, now use induction in the number of sides of the polygon (for the induction step you will need to divide the poligon in two poligons adding a line between two vertices, then the integral in both polygons is equal to the integral of the original poligon)

Comment: @Masacroso I'm not sure how to do that sir., hopefully you could help further in constructing this in math terms. Anyhow, your hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: choose three arbitrary distinct points in $\Bbb C$, say $z_1,z_2$ and $z_3$. Then the path between these three points are a triangle, if $T$ is the triangle you have $$\int_T z^k dz=\int_{z_1\to z_2}z^k dz+\int_{z_2\to z_3} z^k dz+\int_{z_3\to z_1} z^k dz$$ by the properties of the integral, here $z_i\to z_j$ is the straight line from $z_i$ to $z_j$. Each of these lines can be parametrized by a function $\gamma_{i,j}:[0,1]\to\Bbb C,\, t\mapsto z_i(1-t)+z_j t$, thus $$\int_{z_i\to z_j} z^k dz=\int_0^1(\gamma_{i,j}(t))^k\gamma_{i,j}'(t) dt$$

Comment: Now, suppose you already has shown that $\int_T z^k dz=0$, then suppose that this is true for any convex polygon of $n$ vertex or less, then to show it for the a convex polygon of $n+1$ vertex you can write the path over this polygon of $n+1$ vertices as the sum of two closed paths: one over a triangle, and the other over a polygon of $n$ vertex